# Is this function convex? (MINLP practice)

Tags: convex-analysis, nonlinear-optimization

I was recently studying mixed integer nonlinear programming questions from Floudas's "Nonlinear and Mixed-Integer Optimization Fundamentals and Application" and I confronted the question below.

> Suppose that $f(x,y)$ and $g(x,y)$ are convex for each $y$, and $h(x,y)=ax+by$ is a linear function. Define
>   $$v(y) :=\inf_{x\in X}f(x,y)$$
>
> where the infimum is taken over all $x$ in a nonemtpy convex set $X$ such that
>   $$ \qquad \qquad  \ h(x,y)=0,\\
> \qquad \qquad\   g(x,y) \le0.$$

I am confused about how to judge whether the $v(y)$ is convex or not.

Comment: Welcome to math.SE. [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) would allow you to have a good formatting.

Comment: @UniMilky that's awesome, thanks for editing (+1)!

Comment: @Yujie Zha Thank you.

Comment: What do you mean by $v(y)$ is $f(x,y)$?  Also shouldn't the infimum be with respect to $x$?

Comment: @G. Sassatelli Sorry for that,actually i am new to this,and i was reading the book "Nonlinear and Mixed-Integer Optimization Fundamentals and Application",then i confront this question.I found a similar question on the book Convex Optimization,but the condition is f(x,y) ,g(x,y) is convex on (x,y).Thank you for your reply,i will go to look the book.

Comment: @littleO Sorry,I have edited it again.The formula represent that when y is fixed,v(y) is the infimum of the f(x,y) with those constrains.

Comment: What do you mean by $x\in X$? It's probably true that if $X$ is an arbitrary subset of $\Bbb R$ you couldn't guarantee convexity. Also, when you say that $h$ is linear, you mean in the usual sense that $h(x,y)=ax+by$, right? Or are we permitted a $+c$ as well? (I'm assuming that $h:\Bbb R^2\to\Bbb R$, too...)

Comment: @EricStucky Thanks for your edit.X is a nonempty, convex set.

Comment: @EricStucky $h$ is the form of $h(x,y)=ax+by$.And $f(x,y),g(x,y)$ is convex only when $y$ is fixed to a value.

Comment: It is convex if $f$ and $g$ are both convex functions.

Answer (score 0):

As the question is currently stated, $v(y)$ cannot be guaranteed to be convex. For instance, take $X=\Bbb R^2$, $f(x,y)=x^2-y^2$, which is convex for each $y$, and $g=h=0$ (so that $g$ is convex, and $h$ is linear). Then $v(y)=-y^2$ by direct calculation, which is not convex.

This is quite a general setup: if you replace our $f$ by $f(x,y)=x^2+f_0(y)$, then $v=f_0$ and so we can obtain no better behavior than a generic function.

Comment: I haven't given it enough thought, but I suspect that if $f$ and $g$ are truly convex then the statement is true: certainly $X\cap \{(x,y): h(x,y)=0\}$ is a convex set, and I think that if you intersect this with $\{(x,y): g(x,y)\leq 0\}$, that will be convex also. So now $v$ is an infimum of a convex function over convex sets; it very believable that the resulting function is convex.

Comment: Yeah,when $f$ and $g$ are convex on $(x,y)$,it can be proved $v(y)$ is convex by using Jensens' inequality.